# Rails: list accepted values of "validates :inclusion" field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, introspection

I have a model like this

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :kind, :question, :state
  belongs_to :section
  validates :question, :kind, :state, :presence => true
  validates :question, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:section_id]}
  validates :kind, :inclusion => {:in => %w(radio check stars)}
  validates :state, :inclusion => {:in => %w(new active answered canceled)}
end
```

is it posible to list all accepted values for some field ? For example get the list of %w(radio check stars) from the field "kind"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a nicer way to do this, but some playing around in the console got me this:

```
Question.validators_on(:kind).select{|v| v.kind_of? ActiveModel::Validations::InclusionValidator}.first.options
# => {:in=>["radio", "check", "stars"]}`
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit more succinct

`VALID_KINDS = %w(radio check stars)
 validates_inclusion_of :kind, in: VALID_KINDS`

[documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_inclusion_of)